# MATLAB: Getting an overview of user-adjustable properties in a GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm working on an extensive Matlab based GUI that was created with GUIDE. Saving the full state of a GUI seems to be a laborious task as it is generally impossible to efficiently make a self-contained copy of the handles structure. From what I've gathered in my web searches, the current work-around is to manually create a new structure and store the necessary properties of all the `uicontrols` in the GUI in appropriately named fields. For example if there's a `uitable` in the GUI, you might want to include in the new structure a field called `tabledata` where you store the `Data` from the `uitable`. The idea is then to save this new structure to a `.mat` file and load the state of the GUI again by reading this file and doing the inverse exercise of manually copying fields.

I called the above a work-around instead of a solution because it's quite laborious for a large GUI. If anyone has a better/quicker/shorter/cleaner way to do this, please feel free to share! I've come up with a shorter and from some points of view cleaner way myself, but there are a few reasons why I might still prefer the above work-around. In any case my question is about that work-around.

The biggest problem with it is that your saving and loading code must be inclusive: every value and property that can be adjusted by the user should be saved into the newly created structure. For a large GUI it's a real pain, nigh on impossible, to find out which values and properties are adjustable by manually checking everything. Especially with the properties of one `uicontrol` possibly influencing certain properties of one or more other `uicontrols`. So my question is: is there a way to get an overview of all the values and properties that a user can influence for a given GUI?

Comment: [`savefig`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/savefig.html) if you want to snapshot the entire figure window.

Comment: @excaza Do you mean that as an alternative way to save the state of the GUI or as an aid/reminder while implemententing the saving and loading functionality? If A: that's what I came up with as well but this makes for pretty slow loading and it isn't backward compatible since you're not so much saving the state of the GUI as you are saving the entire GUI itself. Loading a state you saved that way in an earlier version of the GUI brings back that earlier version too. If B: I was hoping for something more like an actual overview, e.g. a list of GUI properties that are accessible to the user.

Comment: [`get`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/get.html) returns all properties and property values for a graphics object into a structure.

Comment: @excaza Thanks for the suggestion, but I know how to get the properties and their values. That's not the 'problem'. I was hoping to find a way to list (only) those properties that can be altered by a user of my GUI. For example: if I have 2 `checkboxes` and the second `checkbox`'s `Visible` property is altered by checking and unchecking the first `checkbox`, I'd like the overview to list the `Value` property for the first `checkbox` and both the `Value` and the `Visible` property for the second `checkbox`. I hope I'm making my thoughts clear here.

Comment: MATLAB has no way to discern this, this is information you should know as the developer of the GUI. I'm not really sure why it even matters in the context of saving/loading a GUI's state.

Comment: @excaza A large part of the GUI was already developed when I came into the picture, so I'm only a co-developer here. In any case I think it's going to be hard for anyone to remember every single property that can be affected in an extensive GUI. Sure, looking at the interface I'm probably going to remember/find most of them, but having an overview would make the process a lot more dependable and less cumbersome. Well, I thought it was a stretch for something like this to exist, especially at the level of the code, but one can always hope. Maybe there was some analysis tool, perhaps at runtime.

Comment: @excaza To illustrate why it matters in this context: I could simply save and load the `Value` and/or `String` fields of every `uicontrol` in the GUI and the `Data` field of every `uitable`. However, imagine the scenario with the two `checkboxes` I described in my earlier comment and imagine I checked the first checkbox before saving: then upon loading that saved state the second checkbox would not be visible, even though the first one is checked. I'd hoped to save some time implementing save functionality with the overview I envisioned, but I guess I'm going to have to dig in. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Why not just save the `Value`, `String`, and `Visible` fields? I think you're vastly overcomplicating the problem. Attempting to specially tailor fields for each graphics object based on whether or not they're adjusted is *more* cumbersome than just [generically saving fields based on the object type](https://github.com/StackOverflowMATLABchat/GUIstate).

Comment: @excaza I wouldn't be surprised if I were. I'm just trying to find the ideal solution, which would mean saving exactly that which needs to be saved and nothing more or nothing less. That could be too much to ask or going too far. Even if saving the `Visible` fields for everything is overkill and will lead to loads of superfluous code, it might still be the fastest way, codewise. But then there are `uicontrols` in the GUI that influence yet other objects and different properties. So a generic approach still seems a bit wonky to me. Ah, didn't spot your edit. Hm, I reluctantly agree. :P

Comment: Yea I've been down this route before because I thought it was a good idea but then realized that probably wasn't the best solution because you end up with very large files and you have all sorts of issues with any callbacks you may have written once you load it again if all of the functions aren't on your path etc. In my opinion it is much better to save state to your own custom format rather than relying on a .fig

Answer (score -1):

Look into a function called [uiinspect](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/17935-uiinspect-display-methods--properties---callbacks-of-an-object) coded by Yair Altman. It produces a list of all methods, callbacks, and properties.

A full explanation of how the function work s is located [here](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uiinspect).

[image: Screenshot Below]